# Shoutem builder preview not working

Tags: shoutem

I'm trying to preview the app after making changes to the built in extensions. When i try to preview the app it tries to build the preview but ends up doing nothing and and brings back the same original screen. I'm not getting an error message at all. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great tutorial on how to [modify extensions](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/modifying-extensions). why I think it's not working for you is because you didn't change the starting screen inside of the navigation. The previous screen that you use is from original extension. You need to click on the three dots in the upper right corner to delete the Screen.

Here's the picture:

[image: Delete screen from navigation]

Once you've deleted screen, add your screen from `Custom` category.

Comment: The Page I've added is the main navigation. I've uninstalled the standard and added mine. Still not working

Comment: Did you choose the right layout which you modified?

Comment: I did. Still no luck. What would you recommend next?

Comment: Can you explain exact steps which you did?

Comment: I deleted the standard main navigation in the app and readded my custom navigation. it currently only has one screen with test data.